# Is it possible to invoke DialogFragment from custom view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I've tried to invoke DialogFragment from custom view:

```
DetailsDialogFragment
    .newInstance(newSelectedDate, adapterItems[newPosition].progress)
    .apply {
         show(childFragmentManager, SCORE_DETAILS_DIALOG_TAG)
    }
```

where `DetailsDialogFragment` looks like this:

```
class DetailsDialogFragment : AppCompatDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return requireActivity().let {
            val dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), R.style.CustomDialog)
            dialog.window?.setDimAmount(BaseDialogFragment.SCRIM_OPACITY)
            dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            dialog
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details_dialog, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.rootView.apply {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titleTextView).text = arguments?.getString(ARGS_MONTH)
            findViewById<ActionButton>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.closeImageView).setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(
            month: String,
            score: Int
        ): DetailsDialogFragment {
            return DetailsDialogFragment()
                .apply {
                    arguments = bundleOf(
                        ARGS_MONTH to month,
                        ARGS_SCORE to score
                    )
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But I receive the following error:

```
IllegalStateException: Fragment DetailsDialogFragment has not been attached yet.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:980)
        ...
```

Is it possible to invoke `DialogFragment` from custom view at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this exception is that you're trying to use the `childFragmentManager` of your freshly newly created instance, which is of course not possible since the Dialog fragment hasn't yet has its internals initialized yet (including its `childFragmentManager`).

If you're using AndroidX I'd use the [`findFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#extension-functions-summary) extension method inside your custom view and try to do:

Inside your custom view

```
val dialogFragment = DetailsDialogFragment
    .newInstance(newSelectedDate, adapterItems[newPosition].progress)

dialogFragment.show(findFragment().childFragmentManager, SCORE_DETAILS_DIALOG_TAG)
```